# How to modify \maketitle title page in amsbook?

Tags: titles, page-numbering, blank-page, amsbook

Here is the preamble to my document, plus a little more.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version

%Pour les accents françaises
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\begin{document}

\title[Long Title]{Les Mathématiques}
\author{M. Abdel Guerroui}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Intégrales Correction Problème 1}
```

I'm having a little trouble adjusting to the amsbook style.  Here's what I need:

1. To have no blank pages whatsoever.
2. To have the first page start at #1 and continue through the whole document, not restart at the first chapter.
3. To be able to put the title, author, and a photo on the very first page of the document.

Comment: amsbook is a class for publications of the AMS. I guess they use this layout for a reason and don't want you to change it.

Comment: briefly, 1. [openany], 2. move `\mainmatter` before the page you want to be arabic "1".  i haven't time now to experiment with 3, but will try to do so later.  there may be some side effects if you don't issue the command `\maketitle`, but if you leave that out, you should be able to format the first page using explicit placement commands and ending with `\clearpage`.

Comment: @barbara You are the AMS expert here. Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 9):

1. use option `[openany]` with `\documentclass`.
2. put `\mainmatter` immediately after `\begin{document}` instead of after `\tableofcontents`.

3. here is a modified version of your example that redefines the relevant part of
   `\maketitle`, including only a title, author, and space for a photo; you can adjust spacing as desired.

note that the packages `amsmath` and `amsfonts` have been omitted; they are built into all
ams document classes.

```
\documentclass[openany]{amsbook}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version

%Pour les accents françaises
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\newcommand{\coverpic}{\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \vspace*{1cm}\centering
     photo for first page
     \vspace{1cm}
  \end{minipage}
  }\par
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \begingroup \topskip\z@skip
  \null\vfil
  \centering
  \begingroup
    \LARGE\bfseries
    \@title\par\vspace{24pt}%
    \def\and{\par\medskip}\centering
    \mdseries\authors\par\bigskip
  \endgroup
  \vfil
  \coverpic
  \vspace{10cm}
  \endgroup
  \newpage
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\title[Long Title]{Les Mathématiques}
\author{M. Abdel Guerroui}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intégrales Correction Problème 1}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a very hard-to-find, but very useful advice.  Where did you learn how to do it?

Comment: @Alex -- my day job is tech-support for ams.